# WPF - Knowing which control will end up with focus

Tags: c#, wpf, events, focus

I've been playing around with events in WPF and have so far I've got good mileage out of 'Source' and 'OriginalSource' properties of the event args as well as using the sending control and FocusManager.  Here's the thing, when a chain of events starts firing, is there any way to know what control will be ending up with focus at the end barring any intervening logic throughout the chain of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only reliable way of doing this is actually letting focus change and then handling it in some `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` handler at top view level.

You can then know which control was going to get the focus, and cancel the change with `e.Handled = true`.

PD. There's a function in all UIElements called `PredictFocus`, but it only works with positional traverse changes, not with tab-based changes (or custom focusing).

Comment: Thanks.  Basically, I have a ListView that loads values into textboxes whenever ListView selection changed fires but I also want it to deselect ListViewItems when the cursor selection moves out of the ListView, but only for SOME elements of the UI.  I've managed somewhat control for this by testing the parent StackPanel element of the collection of controls but the code to implement this complicated set of interactions is getting complex and I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the clutter. I'm using a combination of PrevLeftMouseButtonDown, LitsView LostFocus and ListView Sel changed.